# Get the ActionBar to redraw itself?

Tags: android

I'd like to replace the icon used for an ActionBar item at runtime (it appears as an action item on the ActionBar). I'm trying the following:

```
private Map<Integer, Integer> mPendingReplacements = 
    new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> it : mPendingReplacements.entrySet()) {
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(it.getKey().intValue());
        if (item != null) {
            item.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(it.getValue().intValue()));
        }
    }
    mPendingReplacements.clear();

    return true;
}

private void replaceMenuItemIcon(int menuItemId, int drawable) {
    mPendingReplacements.put(menuItemId, drawable);
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
} 

private void onUserClickedSomeButton() {
    replaceMenuItemIcon(R.id.foo, R.drawable.grok);    
}
```

------------ Update -----------

Updated the above sample to use mPendingReplacements as suggested by Selvin. I can see it execute as excepted, but the actionbar icon still doesn't change immediately. Will continue digging into this, but can anyone spot if I'm missing something?

Thank you

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu set icon flag field, call invalidate and in onPrepare select icon based on flag

Comment: Thanks Selvin, the docs make sense and it *should* be working now, seems to execute as expected, still doesn't change immediately though for some reason.

Comment: hmmm one more ... how you creating menu? if from xml file could you share it with us ? if not could you add menu creation code ?(you should inflate/add menu items in onCreateOptionsMenu)

Comment: Ok updated to show how menu is created from xml.